# initState called multiple times

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In my app I have a login screen and a home screen. When navigating from the login to the home screen I read data from a .txt file and show 4 random data points. I am getting the data from the file in my initState so that it isn't called multiple times when the state changes and then waiting on it with a future builder like...

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<bool> _future;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('in initState about to call _getData');
    _future = _getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return new Center(
                child: Text('Error'),
              );
            } else {
              return new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //my view
                ],
              );
            }
          }
        }
    );
    return MaterialApp(
        home: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: futureBuilder,
          ),
        )
    );
```

Now when I navigate back to the login screen using the back button and then go back to the home screen initState will go off multiple times (this can be seen by the print statement I left in). As you go back and forth between these two screens (pop homescreen, push homescreen) initState will be called exponentially more times. I am so confused, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: Full code for both login and home screen can be found https://github.com/ViscousOx/Flutter-Stuff

Comment: Can you show the full widget (stateful class too) + its potential parent?

Comment: @RémiRousselet I uploaded both widgets to github at https://github.com/ViscousOx/Flutter-Stuff

Comment: Did you find the answer for this? I also face the same, I am using `provider` package.

Comment: @RémiRousselet: I am using `provider` package and experiencing the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Try that: It work**
Use the default statement with the ConnectionState.waiting.

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<bool> _future;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    print('in initState about to call _getData');
    _future = _getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var futureBuilder = new FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return new Center(
                child: Text('Error'),
              );
            } else {
              return new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //my view
                ],
              );
            }
          }
        }
    );
    return MaterialApp(
        home: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            body: futureBuilder,
          ),
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection waiting state can be avoided. I used as:

```
FutureBuilder(future: _isUserLoggedIn(),
                     builder: (ctx, loginSnapshot) => 
                      loginSnapshot.data == true ?  AppLandingScreen() : SignUpScreen()
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

> As you go back and forth between these two screens (pop homescreen, push homescreen)

It sounds like you're creating your `HomeScreen` each time you enter the screen, so it'll be a brand new widget, and thus normal that `initState()` gets called.

If you want to keep the same screen (object) around for the lifetime of your app, there are a number of solutions such as `Stack` and `Offstage` so that your widget lives on, but isn't visible.